# Equivalent to boot2docker ip for new docker for windows10/hyperV

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I have used docker toolbox in the past on windows with Virtualbox and boot2docker. Now I installed new docker windows and boot2docker is not recognized anymore when typing

boot2docker ip

What command should I use now for Docker Windows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `localhost`. Docker for Windows (as well as Docker for Mac) are doing some additional magic proxying to automatically forward ports from the host to the IP address of the VM so you shouldn't need to know the IP.

However, there are some caveats on Windows. Check out https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#limitations-of-windows-containers-for-localhost-and-published-ports for more information if you are using Windows containers.

Comment: Wow seems so overcomplicated but thanks for the info. I'm upset that Microsoft is not doing better